# Python asyncio.gather returns None

Tags: python, http, aiohttp, python-asyncio

I'm using Python asyncio to implement a fast http client.

As you can see in the comments below inside the worker function I get the responses as soon as they are finished. I would like to get the responses ordered and this is why I'm using asyncio.gather.

Why is it returning None? Can anybody help?

Thank you so much!

```
import time
import aiohttp
import asyncio

MAXREQ = 100
MAXTHREAD = 500
URL = 'https://google.com'
g_thread_limit = asyncio.Semaphore(MAXTHREAD)


async def worker(session):
    async with session.get(URL) as response:
        await response.read()   #If I print this line I get the responses correctly

async def run(worker, *argv):
    async with g_thread_limit:
        await worker(*argv)

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        await asyncio.gather(*[run(worker, session) for _ in range(MAXREQ)])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    totaltime = time.time()
    print(asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main()))   #I'm getting a None here
    print (time.time() - totaltime)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function `run` doesn't return nothing explicitly, so it returns `None` implicitly. Add return statement and you'll get a result

```
async def worker(session):
    async with session.get(URL) as response:
        return await response.read()


async def run(worker, *argv):
    async with g_thread_limit:
        return await worker(*argv)
```